# Split/Slice large JSON file in Windows using jq

Tags: json, windows, jq

I have some very large (20-100GB) JSON files that I need to split into smaller files. I found the link below for doing so on Linux, but I am working on Windows. I have jq and it works, but I am not fluent enough to be able to write the requisite code. Could someone please translate the Linux answer to Windows for me?

[Split/Slice large JSON using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70627447/split-slice-large-json-using-jq)

Comment: [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/setup/environment) gives you a linux environment inside Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with the Windows quote issues is to put the jq filter code into a file and call it with -f. When you do this you can use the same code that works on Linux.